# Import Telethon Session AWS Lambda

Tags: telethon

I am trying to use Telethon with AWS Lambda. More precisely I am trying get messages from some public channels using client object.

Is there a way to import an existing session in AWS Lambda, in order to prevent Telegram/telethon to ask for a validation code (which is not possible to input) ?

Here is the code I am using to try to connect to telegram through telethon in AWS Lambda :

```
api_id== os.environ.get('TELEGRAM_API_ID')
api_hash = os.environ.get('TELEGRAM_API_HASH')
userName = os.environ.get('TELEGRAM_USERNAME')
phone = os.environ.get('TELEGRAM_PHONE')
os.chdir("/tmp")
client = TelegramClient(userName, api_id, api_hash)
```

Here is the session file I have imported in AWS Lambda through Layers (same name as userName) [session file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYUdA.png)

But it seems the session file is not used/read as telethon is asking the verification code and phone number.

Anyone know how to fix this ? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

It took some time, but I found a solution to this problem and ran a Telegram client on Lambda)

All you need to do is use a different session type, namely StringSession.

As indicated in the [official documentation](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/concepts/sessions.html#string-sessions), all you need to do is generate a StringSession in your local environment, save the string in a file or local variables and use it in your lambda code.

Generate StringSession, you will see the output in your terminal in this case:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.sessions import StringSession

with TelegramClient(StringSession(), api_id, api_hash) as client:
    print(client.session.save())
```

Save your newly created StringSession into environment variables in Lambda, as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html) and now you can do something like this:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.sessions import StringSession

import os 

string = os.environ.get('session') # env variable named "session"

with TelegramClient(StringSession(string), api_id, api_hash) as client:
     client.loop.run_until_complete(client.send_message('me', 'Hi'))
```

Comment: Nice work! Since you seem to be the only confirmed person on the web to have successfully run Telethon from AWS Lambda, it would be great if you updated your answers with complete (or more) code and also described how you created the Telethon layer for lambda. Much appreciated!